# Saving nested objects in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendar, calendarview

I'm using Firebase as my database for my Android project. In this project, I have Event object, contains mCalendar object which is a date of type "Calendar".

```
 mOriginalEvent = new Event(
            id,
            rawTitle.isEmpty() ? null : rawTitle,
            mCalendar,
            mColor,
            mIsCompleteCheckBox.isChecked()
    );
```

**I tried this but it does not works.**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events").child(id).setValue(mOriginalEvent);
```

**when I insert events it keeps crashing**
So How can I save this data to firebase?

......

```
    public Event(String id, String title, Calendar date, int color, boolean isCompleted) {
        mID = id;
        mTitle = title;
        mDate = date;
        mColor = color;
        this.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return mID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public Calendar getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return isCompleted;
    }

    protected Event(Parcel in) {
        mID = in.readString();
        mTitle = in.readString();
        mColor = in.readInt();
        mDate = (Calendar) in.readSerializable();
        isCompleted = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mID);
        dest.writeString(mTitle);
        dest.writeInt(mColor);
        dest.writeSerializable(mDate);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (isCompleted ? 1 : 0));

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Event> CREATOR = new Creator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public Event createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Event(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Event[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Event[size];
        }
    };
}
```

.....................

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Firebase rtdb can only store a limited number of data types. You really should read the documentation. To store a date that you can easily process, I would suggest storing it as an integer eg. milliseconds since epoch.